# Swift: How to remember cookies for further http requests

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, ios9

I am working on a login application. After successful login response comes back with cookie data.
How can I use/save this data for my future requests?
For starters I am trying to save it in `NSHTTPCookieStorage`. But that is also not working.

**Login Method(partial):**

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, responseData, error) -> Void in
            if let response = responseData as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                statusCode = response.statusCode
                print("Response code: \(statusCode)")
            }

            var json: NSDictionary?
            do {
                json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary
            } catch {
                print(error)
                err = error
            }

            if(statusCode != 200) {

                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
            }
            else {

                print("Everything Looks good: \(responseData)")
                self.setCookies(responseData!)
                self.shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier("showHomeController", sender: self)

            }
        }

        task?.resume()
```

**Save Cookie Method**

```
private func setCookies(response: NSURLResponse) {
        if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            let cookies = NSHTTPCookie.cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields(httpResponse.allHeaderFields, forURL: response.URL!) as! [NSHTTPCookie]
            NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().setCookies(cookies, forURL: response.URL!, mainDocumentURL: nil)
            for cookie in cookies {
                var cookieProperties = [String: AnyObject]()
                cookieProperties[NSHTTPCookieName] = cookie.name
                cookieProperties[NSHTTPCookieValue] = cookie.value()
                cookieProperties[NSHTTPCookieDomain] = cookie.domain
                cookieProperties[NSHTTPCookiePath] = cookie.path
                cookieProperties[NSHTTPCookieVersion] = NSNumber(integer: cookie.version)
                cookieProperties[NSHTTPCookieExpires] = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(31536000)

                let newCookie = NSHTTPCookie(properties: cookieProperties)
                NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().setCookie(newCookie!)

                println("name: \(cookie.name) value: \(cookie.value())")
            }
        }
    }
```

**Error:**

```
Cannot invoke 'cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields' with an argument list of type '([NSObject : AnyObject], forURL: NSURL)'
```

Answer (score 39):

If you realize the usage of cookie, the server has to send the header `Set-Cookie` in response to the client request. Just inspect the header in response and you will see `Set-Cookie` header field with cookie in it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Setting_a_cookie

If you use URLSession with default or background `URLSessionConfiguration`, you dont have to make any change to save cookie. If you look at documentation for default `URLSessionConfiguration`, which describes it like this,

> The default session configuration uses a persistent disk-based cache
>   (except when the result is downloaded to a file) and stores
>   credentials in the user’s keychain. It also stores cookies (by
>   default) in the same shared cookie store as the NSURLConnection and
>   NSURLDownload classes.

Also, you can read further about this in `URLSessionConfiguration` documentation for property `httpCookieStorage` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1411599-httpcookiestorage).

Here is a small snippet of code that I will use further to test the cookie storage.

```
let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral
sessionConfiguration.httpCookieAcceptPolicy = .never
let customSession = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)

enum Result {
    case success(HTTPURLResponse, Data)
    case failure(Error)
}

func readCookie(forURL url: URL) -> [HTTPCookie] {
    let cookieStorage = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
    let cookies = cookieStorage.cookies(for: url) ?? []
    return cookies
}

func deleteCookies(forURL url: URL) {
    let cookieStorage = HTTPCookieStorage.shared

    for cookie in readCookie(forURL: url) {
        cookieStorage.deleteCookie(cookie)
    }
}

func storeCookies(_ cookies: [HTTPCookie], forURL url: URL) {
    let cookieStorage = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
    cookieStorage.setCookies(cookies,
                             for: url,
                             mainDocumentURL: nil)
}


func executeURLRequest(url: URL, inSession session: URLSession = .shared, completion: @escaping (Result) -> Void) {
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            let data = data {
            completion(.success(response, data))
            return
        }

        if let error = error {
            completion(.failure(error))
            return
        }

        let error = NSError(domain: "com.cookiesetting.test", code: 101, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Unknown error occurred"])
        completion(.failure(error))
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

**With the snippet above, we firstly test that default session saves the cookie.**

```
var cookies = readCookie(forURL: googleURL)
print("Cookies before request: ", cookies)

executeURLRequest(url: googleURL) { result in
    if case .success (let data) = result {
        cookies = readCookie(forURL: googleURL)
        print("Cookies after request: ", cookies)

        deleteCookies(forURL: googleURL)
        cookies = readCookie(forURL: googleURL)
        print("Cookies after deletion: ", cookies)
    }
}
```

And, here is what we get,

```
Cookies before request:  []
Cookies after request:  [<NSHTTPCookie
    version:0
    name:1P_JAR
    value:2018-09-26-15
    expiresDate:'2018-10-26 15:39:46 +0000'
    created:'2018-09-26 15:39:46 +0000'
    sessionOnly:FALSE
    domain:.google.com
    partition:none
    sameSite:none
    path:/
    isSecure:FALSE
 path:"/" isSecure:FALSE>, <NSHTTPCookie
    version:0
    name:NID
    value:139=E3g4bKNRGcYoeFuaECpfsx_Efp64xONmVwcJS7f7PuZe8LayS5ZkGuz3f7z6eq7zoBm2z-opTvzX8YPzn8v1ebjH6iyt5-6yDYm9RE6XhXwHCZWs98_j7nb11u2EPnHI
    expiresDate:'2019-03-28 15:39:46 +0000'
    created:'2018-09-26 15:39:46 +0000'
    sessionOnly:FALSE
    domain:.google.com
    partition:none
    sameSite:none
    path:/
    isSecure:FALSE
    isHTTPOnly: YES
 path:"/" isSecure:FALSE isHTTPOnly: YES>]
Cookies after deletion:  []
```

`URLSessionConfiguration` also has a property `httpCookieAcceptPolicy`, which quotes the following:

> This property determines the cookie accept policy for all tasks within
>   sessions based on this configuration.
>
> The default value is
>   HTTPCookie.AcceptPolicy.onlyFromMainDocumentDomain. You can change it
>   to any of the constants defined in the HTTPCookie.AcceptPolicy
>   enumerated type.
>
> If you want more direct control over what cookies are accepted, set
>   this value to HTTPCookie.AcceptPolicy.never and then use the
>   allHeaderFields and cookies(withResponseHeaderFields:for:) methods to
>   extract cookies from the URL response object yourself.

So, if you wish to manipulate the cookie by yourself, you could set the `httpCookieAcceptPolicy` to `never`.

**Following code shows, cookie not stored when using httpCookieAcceptPolicy to never,**

```
var cookies = readCookie(forURL: googleURL)
print("Cookies before request: ", cookies)

executeURLRequest(url: googleURL, inSession: customSession) { result in
    if case .success (let data) = result {
        cookies = readCookie(forURL: googleURL)
        print("Cookies after request: ", cookies)

    }
}
```

Which logs the following;

```
Cookies before request:  []
Cookies after request:  []
```

You can see that using .never for httpCookieStoragePolicy, system wont store cookie to shared cookie storage.

You can also store the cookie yourself, which would look like this,

**Storing the cookie by ourselves**

```
deleteCookies(forURL: googleURL)
var cookies = readCookie(forURL: googleURL)
print("Cookies before request: ", cookies)
executeURLRequest(url: googleURL, inSession: customSession) { result in
    if  case let .success  (response, data) = result {
        guard let cookiesResponseHeader = response.allHeaderFields["Set-Cookie"] else {
            return
        }

        cookies = readCookie(forURL: googleURL)
        print("Cookies after request: ", cookies)

        let responseCookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: response.allHeaderFields as! [String: String], for: googleURL)
        storeCookies(responseCookies, forURL: googleURL)
        cookies = readCookie(forURL: googleURL)
        print("Cookies after storing: ", cookies)

    }
}
```

And, here is what the code above prints to console,

```
Cookies before request:  []
Cookies after request:  []
Cookies after storing:  [<NSHTTPCookie
    version:0
    name:1P_JAR
    value:2018-09-26-18
    expiresDate:'2018-10-26 18:35:23 +0000'
    created:'2018-09-26 18:35:23 +0000'
    sessionOnly:FALSE
    domain:.google.com
    partition:none
    sameSite:none
    path:/
    isSecure:FALSE
 path:"/" isSecure:FALSE>, <NSHTTPCookie
    version:0
    name:NID
    value:139=D7GTUazWfeaB5Bcu1wN5I_Il2k6xALNiRZDX_DN9totQbnrP31gE0GzlsjCHDISUv8ulPq9G8Yu1p-GsZcVRw2fnrBROih-vtAVBic5UXFKUkG_ZbFQYKFprr4MPHDGS
    expiresDate:'2019-03-28 18:35:23 +0000'
    created:'2018-09-26 18:35:23 +0000'
    sessionOnly:FALSE
    domain:.google.com
    partition:none
    sameSite:none
    path:/
    isSecure:FALSE
    isHTTPOnly: YES
 path:"/" isSecure:FALSE isHTTPOnly: YES>]
```

The code above uses `.never` HTTPCookieAcceptPolicy to URLSessionConfiguration but we create cookie from response and store it to the cookie store by ourselves.

Comment: Can I just send the next request with something like `let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://google.com/user")!)`?

Answer (score 1):

> class func cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields(_ headerFields: [String :
>   String], forURL URL: NSURL) -> [NSHTTPCookie]

Note that headerFields is [String: String] Dictionary and the compiler is complaining that you're passing [NSObject : AnyObject]

Answer (score 1):

for URLSession connection you can use this(after you received your first response) :

```
var cookies =  URLSession.shared.configuration.httpCookieStorage?.cookies
```

and you can use these cookies like this:

```
var session = URLSession.self
session.shared.configuration.httpCookieStorage?.setCookies(cookies, for: baseurl, mainDocumentURL: baseurl)
    let task = session.shared.dataTask(with: url)
```