# How to get 2 different webviews with 2 different NSURLSession (iOS Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a iOS App with 2 Webviews (1 Shop, 1 Logged-In Shop)

If I login in one webview, the other webview includes the same cookies and the first webview is logged in too.

I need the first one to have it's own session (cookies)!

My plan is to have a saved login Touch-ID protected and a free everyone can use webview.

I was currently searching for 2 and a half hours and tried stuff like:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://www.my-url.com")!)
    request.setValue("", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")
    webView.loadRequest(request)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes , you can save your cookies to the first webview from `webViewDidFinishLoad`:

```
let storage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
for cookie in storage.cookies as! [NSHTTPCookie]{
    print(cookie)
}
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

If you set to the second webview to the `loadRequest`:

```
var req = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
var storage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookies as! [NSHTTPCookie]

var reqCookies:[AnyObject] = []

for aCookie in storage {

    reqCookies += [aCookie]

}

var headers = NSHTTPCookie.requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies(reqCookies)

self.webView.loadRequest(req)
```

Otherwise you can delete:

```
let storage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
for cookie in storage.cookies! {
   storage.deleteCookie(cookie)
}
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

**EDIT** (after comments): to manage different sessions you can look in this Stackoverflow answer to [handle your different sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31465649/1894067).

Comment: Hi Alessandro, 

thanks for the fast answer, but I have the opposite problem.
I have the 2 Webviews and the default behavior is that the views have the sharedStorage.

My plan is to have completly diffrent sessions, like having to browsers around.

The problem is: I can set the cookies, but changing the page of the webview will retrieve the other session again.

Comment: This part was not clear in your question..If you want to handle different session you must change the default cookies policies thinking to NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyNever and then use the allHeaderFields and cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:forURL: methods to extract cookies from the URL response object yourself.